# Write a custom "editable" directive with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm studying angularjs, and I want to write a custom "editable" directive, which can make a normal html element "editable":

When user clicks it, it will show a text input or textarea to let user edit the content, and there is also a "update" and "cancel" button besides. User can click the "update" button or press "Ctrl+enter" to submit the modified content, or click "cancel" or press "escape" to cancel the modification.

The "editable" signature looks like:

```
<div editable 
     e-trigger="click|dblclick"       /* use click or dblclick to trigger the action */
     e-update-url="http://xxx/xxx"    /* when submitting, the data will PUT to this url */
     e-singleline="true|false"        /* if ture, use text input, otherwise textarea */
     ng-model="name">                 /* the corresponding model name */
{{name}}
</div>
```

I've create a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Freewind/KRduz/, you can just update it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am new to Angular myself, and hope you would get the a working example with your fiddle. Meanwhile, John Lindquist has an excellent video where he explains how to create a markdown tag to embed an editor. Which has details on how to make an editable and preview regions with angular directives.

- [Part 2](http://youtu.be/nKJDHnXaKTY)
- [Part 1](http://youtu.be/A6wq16Ow5Ec)

Comment: While the videos are great, I would like to see a summary here.

Answer (score 7):

First I'd watch the John Lindquist angularjs videos that bsr posted - they are very good. Then, I'd check out the directive I threw together below.

```
.directive('editable', function() {
    var editTemplate = '<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" \
        ng-show="inEditMode" ng-dblclick="switchToViewMode()" \
        class="form-control input-sm">';
    var viewTemplate = '<div ng-hide="inEditMode" \
        ng-dblclick="switchToEditMode()">{{ value }}</div>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '=ngModel',
            bindAttr: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.inputValue = $scope.value;
        },
        replace: true,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            tElement.html(editTemplate);
            tElement.append(viewTemplate);

            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.inEditMode = false;

                scope.switchToViewMode = function() {
                    scope.inEditMode = false;
                    scope.value = scope.inputValue;
                }
                scope.switchToEditMode = function() {
                    scope.inEditMode = true;
                }
                scope.toggleMode = function() {
                    scope.inEditMode = !scope.inEditMode;
                }

                element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.switchToViewMode();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is exactly how it should be done IMO. Here's all you need to do to include an editable:

```
<editable ng-model="name"></editable>
```

Good to go.

Answer (score 7):

Please have a look on angular-xeditable:
http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable

Answer (score 4):

I started by making an example which works. I guess it should not be too much work to turn it into a directive with all the options you want.

My thought is - don't try to do too much in one directive, perhaps it can be achieved with quite a few smaller directives.

http://jsfiddle.net/Saulzar/rueHv/

Answer (score 0):

use e-addYourDirectiveName

```html
 <span editable-text="university.ValueAr" e-only-arabic-letters-input e-name="ValueAr" e-form="UniversityForm">  </span>
```

letters-input e-name="ValueAr" e-form="UniversityForm" onbeforesave="checkValue($data)">
                                        {{ university.ValueAr }}

Comment: This provided snippet is hard to repair. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the answer?